# Android Map show marker Title and Snippet

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a google map in my android app and want to show the marker title when it loads here is what I have

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(lat, lng)).title(name);
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

But then how can I show the maker title?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Right now I have

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(lat, lng)).zoom(14).build();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

[image]

But then the marker is cut off, how can I have it so the marker is also seen

Comment: tap on the marker and you can see the title popping up.

Comment: @Lal sorry I meant to say I want to do it programatically, without having the user touch it

Comment: Okay..check my answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show the Marker title programmatically, you can just do this

```
myMarker=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
myMarker.showInfoWindow();
```

**UPDATE**

To make the infoWindow fit inside the view, try

```
int zoom = (int)mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), zoom), 4000, null);
```

Please dont forget to add this before opening the info window.

Comment: great thanks, and then is there a way to make sure that it is also in the view?

Comment: you can use `animateCamera()` like `mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 15.5f), 4000, null);`

Comment: Try zooming out..that is try giving a smaller value for `zoom()`.

Comment: did that is just makes the red marker larger and the text is still off screen?

Comment: you have to zoom out...what is the current value for zoom?

Comment: try some value like `6` or so for `zoom()`